# Is there a way to backup all my files and replace with 0-byte files with same name?

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup

My main drive on laptop keeps filling up so I take a backup on a USB and delete the original files. But then I find myself getting (downloading or getting from someone else) files that I already have backed-up but couldn't recall at the moment.

So is there a way I can keep a 0-byte file with the same name as teh backed-up copy so that when I'm asked whether to overwrite the existing file, I can easily choose no knowing I probably have this file already in the backup.

EDIT: better yet, replace with a shortcut(.lnk) on the external drive so I can access the files hassle free and not get any errors because of 0-byte files being accidentally opened.

<s>***somewhat* solution:** There's no software or utility that does this automatically I think. I'm just writing out procedure I found best to solve my issue for reference.</s>

- Backup the home drive (D:) onto Backup drive (E:)
- Delete any and all files you don't want from D now that they're "back-ed up".
- Use [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) to create SymbolicLinkClone of both (D:) and (E:) in separate folders "d" and "e" in (D:)

I've found that you can copy over (overwrite) the contents of the folder "d" onto "e" but not onto (D:).

- So overwrite "e" with "d" and copy what you can from "d" to (D:).

I guess it'll be more involved than this for future backups though.

This isn't reliable it seems.

Comment: Are all the files in a single folder structure?

Comment: No they're all over, and in sub-directories.

Comment: Well if you can generate a list somehow, perhaps from the backup utility you use, then it should be straightforward

Comment: I can only think of manually writing a batch script or something. But it won't be that easy for me, especially dealing with new backups.

Comment: sticking with the shortcut idea, might keep from having misteaks happen more often. Process in groups create the shorts in groups.  One copy is not a backup :-)

Comment: I agree, I shouldn't have use backup in that sense. But I think SYMLINKs are the answer to my needs right now. They're 0-bytes and you can't copy them over (overwrite) onto the original(source) files. Free [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) works perfectly for that. Though I still have to manually do the backup and create links.

Comment: advantage of symlinks: Symbolic links can point to non existent targets because the operating system does not check to see if the target exists, wheras shortcuts are a pain when the item is removed.

Comment: @Psycogeek: in NTFS, very small files (<=16 bytes IIRC) live directly in the master file table and don't take up a cluster.  But I've just tried it out and symbolic links do indeed use a cluster - I guess the path information is more than 16 bytes. :-)

Comment: How are you guys checking the size? In Properties dialog box it shows 0 for both Size and Size On Disk.

Comment: I had not yet checked the size, I was only using logic, the data has to be stored somewhere. I just did a cluster analisis ,after making Massive quantites of symlinks. The quantity of space used is very minimal. the clusters used for the "folder" the links are in is what increased. And Hidden file $Extend\$Reparse:$R:$Index_Allocation I did not look into the MFT, that would be interesting. . . Simple Files size things could have 2 problems, showing the size of the files they link to, and assuming that the link "take no space" which is only virtually correct :-)

Comment: I don't really understand your question. You have 2 drives, A and B.  You copy files from A to B, and make the copied files 0 bytes at A. Why? So that you know it got copied so you don't copy it again, is that why? And what did you mean about overwriting? Overwriting would be A to B wouldn't it? Where do 0 byte files fit into copying A to B?

Comment: I don't wanna keep two copies. If it's "back-ed up" I wanna delete the file from (A:). But I still want the file to be there on (A:) so that I know that it's there in my backup drive (B:) without taking up any space on (A:). I admit it isn't really backing up as Psycogeek says but I couldn't really think of a word that describes this scenario.

Comment: Keeping it organised.  From what I understand so far, LaggingReflex would like to have each of the file items exist Virtually without taking much space, so they know what is already done , what already exists. Then various features of that like notification of overwrite , quick viewing using the Same explorer Interface, not needing a notepad, or catalog, shows in File search tool.  link access when it is connected.   I do some similar things for other organisation reasons, when a faux file makes the best placeholder.